# Ruby input output issue

Tags: ruby

A simple issue, but can't figure out how to solve it, lacking knowledge in Ruby language:

```
class Game
  def initialize
    get_command
  end
  def get_command
    command = gets
    puts command                # => POSITION
    puts command != "POSITION"  # => true
    if command != "POSITION"
      command = get_command 
    else  
      return true
    end
  end
end

a = Game.new
```

Whenever I run an application and type `POSITION` it always gets the `true` comparing to `"POSITION"` can anyone explain why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because what you're actually getting is "POSITION\n". You can see this in irb:

```
1.9.3p194 :061 > command = gets
POSITION
 => "POSITION\n"
```

You should strip the command before doing comparisons:

```
command = gets.strip
```

or

```
command = gets.chomp
```

This will strip whitespace (including newlines) off of the input.

Comment: Always a good idea to sanitize user input -- especially since the end-of-line character is different on different platforms